# What's the difference between a conviction that is spent and one that is expunged?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-terms, definition

This came up in the comments thread of [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/79770/35069) so it was suggested to ask it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Spent** means the sentence etc has been served and, under certain conditions, one need not disclose one's criminal history as they are deemed rehabilitated. See the [Rehabilitation of Offenders Act 1974](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1974/53/contents) and [NARCO](https://www.nacro.org.uk/criminal-record-support-service/support-for-individuals/disclosing-criminal-records/disclosing-criminal-records-employers/):

> Once a conviction, caution, reprimand or final warning becomes spent, you do not need to disclose it to most employers, or when applying for most courses, insurance or other purposes (e.g. applying for housing)...

**Expunged** means the conviction etc has been quashed as though it never existed. The [online OED](https://www.lexico.com/definition/expunge) defines it as:

> Obliterate or remove completely (something unwanted or unpleasant)

Note that the term used by in legislation is **Quash[ed]**, as per [section 2(2)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1968/19/section/2?timeline=false) of the Criminal Appeal Act 1968:

> In the case of an appeal against conviction the Court shall, if they allow the appeal, quash the conviction.

Comment: So "expunged" means the conviction was wrong in the first place and should never have happened (in a perfect world)?

Comment: I think this comment should be integrated into the answer.

Comment: @gnasher729 no, expunged means the conviction is so old that it no longer appears on a criminal record. It does not mean that the conviction never happened. It is different from one that has been overturned or pardoned.

Answer (score -3):

A spent conviction has had its punishment served.

An [expunged](https://unlock.org.uk/advice/retention-deletion-police-records/) conviction is one that has been served and is so old (I.e. there is a statutory time limit) that it can no longer be reported for particular purposes. Usually on a police record although there may be different grades of police record - you maybe expunged in some but not on others. For example, certain convictions may not appear on publicly available records but may be available to police or courts.

Comment: Do you have any reputable sources for this? Maybe things are different in your jurisdiction but "Spent" in E&W has a specific meaning beyond "punishment served" which is, near enough, the same as your definition of expunged.